# How I can add tools/actions/buttons to the Command Center of VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to have some actions on the Command Center in VS Code near by navigation buttons, somethings like `Copy relative path`, `Reveal in Explorer View`, etc. How can I do it, and is it possible without creating an extension?
[image]

Comment: I was looking after the same, would be highly useful, right now Im adding some buttons in the status bar that would be better up there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way to configure this at the time of this writing. The only setting with "commandcenter" in it is `window.commandCenter`, which is just to toggle it. Looking through the [extension API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api), I see no mention of the command center.

A feature-request has been raised by the asker of this question: [Command Center customization #185316](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185316). You can give it a thumbs up to show support for it and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and updates. Please avoid making noisy comments there like "+1" / "bump".

Also related: [User configurable menus #9285](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/9285).